# Add DAL project to Web API (Restful) project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rest, asp.net-web-api, dependencies

I have a Web API project used as a restful web service.

I add all my bean (POCO) classes into the `Model` folder.

Now I want to add another project that should be the DAL to my whole solution.

I need the DAL to know my bean classes but also that my Web API project will reference to my DAL project - and this of course make a circular dependency.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to put all my Bean in other project?

What did I miss here?

Answer (score 1):

It's not good idea to have reference from DAL to Web project. But if you really need it you can create your POCO classes in Model folder inherited from some interfaces and put interfaces to third library.

Comment: So what is the correct architecture ? if I have a DAL project it must know the POCO

Comment: The entities or POCO classes should either be in their own project or in the DAL project. Generally, I put them into their own project. As Keen said, do not have the DAL reference the Web API.